# XSLT - Group child nodes under same parent

Tags: xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have the following input XML

**Input XML**

```
<bills>
    <bill>
        <billNo>1</billNo>
        <exportType>1</exportType>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>1</serialNo>
        </invoice>
    </bill>
    <bill>
        <billNo>1</billNo>
        <exportType>1</exportType>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>2</serialNo>
        </invoice>
    </bill>
    <bill>
        <billNo>2</billNo>
        <exportType>1</exportType>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>1</serialNo>
        </invoice>
    </bill>
    <bill>
        <billNo>2</billNo>
        <exportType>1</exportType>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>2</serialNo>
        </invoice>
    </bill>
    <bill>
        <billNo>2</billNo>
        <exportType>1</exportType>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>3</serialNo>
        </invoice>
    </bill>
</bills>
```

that needs to be converted to an output XML

**Output XML**

```
<bills>
    <bill>
        <billNo>1</billNo>
        <exportType>1</exportType>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>1</serialNo>
        </invoice>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>2</serialNo>
        </invoice>
    </bill>
    <bill>
        <billNo>2</billNo>
        <exportType>1</exportType>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>1</serialNo>
        </invoice>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>2</serialNo>
        </invoice>
        <invoice>
            <serialNo>3</serialNo>
        </invoice>
    </bill>
</bills>
```

The following XSLT is being used for transformation however I am missing something as the child nodes under `bill` also get repeatedly copied instead of only the `invoice`child node and its children getting copied. XSL is as below

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:key name="key" match="bill" use="billNo" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="bill[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key', billNo)[1])]">
        <bill>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('key', billNo)/*" />
        </bill>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="bill" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the expected result is to change this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('key', billNo)/*" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="billNo | exportType" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('key', billNo)/invoice" />
```

---

Note that this assumes that the `exportType` is the same for all items grouped under a common `billNo`.

Comment: `exportType` and `billNo` are not the only children under `bill` hence cannot add `<xsl:apply-templates select="billNo | exportType" />`. There are more children and only the `invoice` needs to be grouped retaining the all other children since the child values are repeated. Is there something like `copy` remaining children and not `invoice`. I have reduced the XML and put it forth as an example.

Comment: @AniketV You can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::invoice)]" />` to copy all elements except `invoice`.

Comment: This suggested change has worked for me. I have accepted the answer.